# Date Range or Columns values entered in Prompt need to be used as variables in Spotfire IL modified SQL

Tags: spotfire

I need to use the prompted input of a date range/any column to be used as a variable in the modified SQl feature of the Information Link. I have some complex queries which uses multiple conditions and i wont be able to keep them in the view and want to add those conditions in modified SQL using this variable.

This is a sample SQL where i need to use the variable/parameter instead of the dates given

```
SELECT xxxxx.yyyy

  FROM xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx

WHERE xxxxx.yyyyy = xxxxx.yyyyy


   AND ( ((    xxxxx.yyyy >= (TO_DATE ('11/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.yyyy <  (TO_DATE ('12/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.zzzzz >=    (TO_DATE ('11/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.zzzzz < (TO_DATE ('12/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) ))

        OR ((    xxxxx.zzzzz >= (TO_DATE ('11/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.zzzzz < (TO_DATE ('12/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.yyyy =  (TO_DATE ('01/01/1753', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) ))

        OR ((    xxxxx.zzzzz >=  (TO_DATE ('11/01/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.zzzzz < (TO_DATE ('12/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.yyyy > (TO_DATE ('10/15/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY'))
             AND xxxxx.yyyy <  (TO_DATE ('12/1/2015', 'MM/DD/YYYY')) )) )
```

I need the above where conditions to be added into the Information link modified SQL with the parameter to be like this

```
WHERE xxxxx.yyyyy = xxxxx.yyyyy


       AND ( ((    xxxxx.yyyy >= @parameter1
                 AND xxxxx.yyyy <  @parameter2
                 AND xxxxx.zzzzz >=    @parameter1
                 AND xxxxx.zzzzz < @parameter2
```

Let me know if further clarification is required.

Comment: This is usually handled better in a procedure. Are you able to convert your `VIEW` to a `STORED PROCEDURE` by chance? If not we can work on the view but since you are parameterizing it, a procedure makes more sense

Comment: I am not much used to _procedure_ and hoping to find a way with _view_ itself

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This will only work for one condition. That is >= or <= to all of the dates in **xxxxx.yyyy** column. So, if you **MUST** use a view then you need to use *prompts* in the information designer. Here is how:

1. Open your Information Link in Information Designer
2. Leave your SQL alone. Set the date range to the largest range you'll need
3. Under the **Prompts** section, *Add* a prompt for your **xxxxx.yyyy** column
4. Set the *Prompt Type* to *Range* and check the *Mandatory* box

Now, add the Information Link to your analysis...

1. When the prompt window opens, select the *Use On-demand* button at the bottom. Select OK/ Finish
2. On the Tool Bar go to *Edit > Data Table Properties* and select your data table
3. Select the *Settings* button under *Type of data:* within the **General** tab
4. Highlight your **xxxxx.yyyy** column and click the *Define Input* button
5. Select *Values (fixed/properties/expression)* from the drop down for **Input for the selected parameter**
6. Select the *Property* radio button and click the *Select* button
7. Click *New* and create a property control of type DATE which you will use in a text area

Again, this is not the ideal way. If you TRULY want to use multiple parameters in multiple conditions, we need to convert your view to a procedure or table-valued function. it's not hard.

---

**EDIT**

```
CREATE PROCEDURE dbo.myProcedure(@parameter1 datetime, @parameter2 datetime)
AS

SELECT xxxxx.yyyy

FROM xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx, xxxxx

WHERE xxxxx.yyyyy = xxxxx.yyyyy

     AND xxxxx.yyyy >= @parameter1
     AND xxxxx.yyyy < @parameter2
     AND xxxxx.zzzzz >= @parameter1
     AND xxxxx.zzzzz < @parameter2
```

Then, you can test the execution by entering this in a new SSMS window.

```
EXEC dbo.myProcedure '4/1/2016','7/1/2016' --or what ever dates you want to pass in.
```

Comment: Thanks for the info. I wanted to know if its possible to create variables and  use it at the Information link level. I know about the Data on Demand setting but i wanted all the calculation in the backend and it seems a proc/functions will be better suited since i have few sub-queries with the same conditions. I dont know to write complex functions and that will be problem.

Comment: Well you can use this same method and give them default values and the user will never be prompted. If you can paste your code for your view we can create the procedure

Comment: thanks for the help but cant use the code publicly, will try to find some other way

Comment: There are many examples on how to turn this into a procedure. I'll edit my answer to give you an example.

Comment: I am able to do my requirement using `?param` in IL by modifying the SQL. The only problem is,it is an one time prompt when the data is opened from IL its not working like a prompt where we can give different values every time we open a report. Is there a way where we can set the `?param` in data on demand option so that new values can be given every time the report is opened

Comment: It worked! I had issue when the Report with parameter was opened in Webplayer but it woked when opened in Client. The parameter defined is visible in the Data on Demand and i was able to add it to the Input Field [Multiple Lines] property control. Single input gave the desired output. Now i am back to square one. Multiple lines can be input for string property and i read it in help. I am not able to enter multiple lines of input and when entered output does'nt come,but with single input it does. For now i am entering nos[eg.134433] as a string input for the param. Need muliple line i/p to work

Comment: You need to either use multiple parameters, or use a comma delimited parameter and, in your procedure, you'll call a split string function which will break each comma deliited value out into a 1 column table, like an array, to join to in your SQL statement. This is too long to explain in a comment though. I've explained quite a bit in response to your original post.

Comment: Finally, i am close to my rqmt using Function since it was easier to implement. Now my issue is that i am not able to make a parameter declared as date to get i/p in 'mm/dd/yyyy' format. The same param when declared as varchar2 was able to get data thro data on demand but for getting the date in prompt i need to add some date column and Spotfire was not able to take it as a string and pass it to the param n the function. Let me know if explanation is vague cos i can ask limited questions in stack,will try to elaborate my problem there. Ur exp with oracle function will help resolve issue

Comment: @direwolf I would open a NEW question for this parameter issue so you can elaborate on your issue. Also, I suggest accepting this answer for future posts if it answered your question, or vote it up if it was helpful. It's why we help.