# Spotfire - Information Link - Filter Not Working

Tags: sql, filter, element, spotfire

I am a beginner in Spotfire. I developed a simple information link.

Steps

1. I Created 2 tables by adding columns.
2. Then created Joins. 3 simple inner joins on the above table. The reason for 3 joins is it makes the query run faster than only 1 join.
3. Then created an information link by adding elements and joins.

This works perfectly well. The data is fetched properly. But as soon as I add filter, it stops working.

I tried

1. Creating Filter -> and then adding as element to the information link
2. Adding filter in the column filter itself: `Column E_ID - Expression %1 = 1000`
3. Editing the sql query in the information link. I added one more
   clause in the where section: `AND E1."E_ID" = 1000`

None of these work. If I remove the filter, its working perfectly fine. The filter is on the same column on which on of the join is based.

Please suggest where I am making mistake.

Comment: thank you @scsimon for editing my post.

Comment: Any help for this problem?

Comment: Where are your two tables hosted?  A SQL database or two excel files or...?

Comment: SQL server database.

Comment: are your joins done in the db, or in the information designer?

Comment: Join is done in the information link.

Comment: If i execute the same sql query as shown in the information link, it executes successfully in sql server database.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Too long to comment...

So, I've noticed joins in the information designer can be cumbersome. It's convenient for people who don't have access to the data source, but if you do have access to the data source (as you do in this scenario), I would handle all of the logic on the DB server side. Thus, you are just supplying Spotfire with a flat file which it can easily ingest and create visualizations on. This will prevent Spotfire from bogging down with data transformations as well.

With that being said, I would also recommend using Stored procedures to serve up the data to Spotfire. Here are a couple of answers I posted on why which will make your life easier.

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247931/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/39640197/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/43523380/6167855

https://stackoverflow.com/a/38247931/6167855

Comment: Thank you. I will either view or stored procedure and see if it works for me. but if a user does not have access to data source, what options do they have?

Comment: I just want to see once, how the information link - filter functionality works. Now I am trying to create information link for a single table (no joins) and adding filter to it. tried it couple of ways and still i am getting empty result set. A simple where criteria on single table should work. What is wrong?

Comment: Sorry. My bad. I was connecting to wrong database. Admin please close this thread.

Comment: No need to close it mate, it happens to the best of us. Sorry i just got to read your comments.